ros_gz_sim build from source error with missing lib gflags
While building ros_gz from source on docker with ROS 2 humble, I encountered the following error, so I thought of posting the solution in case someone has the same error in the future.
--- stderr: ros_gz_sim
/workspaces/gazebo_test/src/ros_gz/ros_gz_sim/src/create.cpp:15:10: fatal error: gflags/gflags.h: No such file or directory
   15 | #include <gflags/gflags.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.


install missing dependency using sudo apt install libgflags-dev
